# Need to convert a form field to a integer

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

Take this example of what object I am currently sending to the backend...

```
{"owner_id":"Rocky","address":"Test","state":"Test","sale_price":"Test"}
```

But my intentions is to send it back like this

```
{"owner_id": 1, "address":"Test","state":"Test","sale_price":"Test"}
```

The issue is.... the key "owner_id" is supposed to be the id integer of Rocky and my backend wont save this because "owner_id" is supposed to be an integer and not a string.

To clarify to next part of this explanation, I am selecting a name from a dropdown on my frontend with an id of "owner_id" btw.

I have my owner name drop setup like this:

```
let dropdown = document.getElementById('owner_id');
dropdown.innerHTML= `` //disappear
  fetch(OWNERS_URL)
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(owners => {
    owners.forEach(owner => {
    dropdown.innerHTML += `<option data-id = ${owner.id} = ${owner.id}>${owner.name}</option>`
    })
    
  })
```

You'll notice that I have the data-id attribute set to ***owner.id*** to associate that option with the name, which when I look at my inspector in my dev tool the option element is setup as intended

```
<option data-id="1">Rocky</option>
```

Below is the code that is handling the submission of the property listing(though I believe this might be irrelevant

```
function ListForm(){
     let owner_id = document.getElementById('owner_id').value
     let address = document.getElementById('address').value
     let state = document.getElementById('state').value
     let sale_price = document.getElementById('sale_price').value
    
     const listing = {
      owner_id: owner_id,
      address: address,
      state: state,
      sale_price: sale_price
    }

    // const formData = new FormData(listForm)
    const listObj = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(listing),
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json"
       }
      }
      
      fetch(PROPERTIES_URL, listObj)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((listing) => {
        let new_listing = renderListing(listing)
        listings.append(new_listing)
        
        console.log(new_listing)
      })
  } 
   
  listForm.addEventListener('submit',(event) =>{
     event.preventDefault();   
     ListForm()
     listForm.reset()
    

  })
```

Also here is my property controller create action on the backend as well as the schema for it.

```
def create
       
        property = Property.create(prop_params)
        
      
        if property.save
            
            render json: property
        else
            render json: { error: "Couldn't save"}
        end
    end

 def prop_params
        params.permit(:id, :address, :state, :sale_price, :owner_id, owner_attributes: [:id, :name, :phone_number,:real_estate_agent])
    end
```

#the schema

```
create_table "properties", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "owner_id"
    t.string "address"
    t.string "state"
    t.string "sale_price"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end
```

What do I need to do in my code base or change in it that will get me the result that I am looking for as initially mentioned?

Comment: [option tags](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp) have a `value` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the `value` property:

```
dropdown.innerHTML += `<option value=
```

Comment: Good news is it is ready the 1 value....but not sure if it supposed to return this though "1" as in owner_id: "1". Is it supposed to do this?

Comment: If your backend can't handle it then just do `parseInt(owner_id)` in your `const listing`